# Having issues with div layouts

Tags: html, css

new here and I'm crossing fingers for help.

I'm working on http://www.catgriz.com

On the frontpage I have a slideshow that stacks all of the information on top of itself when you initially visit the page.  But after a simple browser refresh, it displays correctly.

I was hoping someone could look at it and point me in the right direction of what I've done wrong.  I'm using Joomla with a Yootheme.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: I have no any issues with your webpage. Let me guess, your problem is in the low internet connection speed. But at the second time when you "refresh" your page, it's cached already and works fast.

Comment: Seem that working just fine in my side too. Please try to clear your joomla cache, browser cache, mysql session table and log out from administrator when testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sliders can produce flickering effect during page load, depending on the amount of elements in each slide, caching, internet speed etc.

You should hide all slides, except first one via css.

```
.slides > li { 
    display: none;
}
.slides > li:first-child {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Widgetkit plugin will do the rest after page loads.

ps. Like the others, I actually didn't saw any problem on your site.